# How to integrate a new QA Engineer in a established dev team

Tags: scrum, agile, team-management, kanban, quality-management

Does anyone have any tips or advice of how to integrate a new junior QA Engineer into a established, highly technical dev team.

Comment: Can you clarify the relationship between this question and project management?  Would this be more appropriate in workplace.SE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no clear connection to project management.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace, I personally think integrating team members well and creating the right environment for their contribution to a koint effort is something that a PM should hold himself accountable for. Even though some might argue that it's a management responsibility to ensure this. But along that line of reasoning, you would also be asking a manager to lead a SCRUM session. There's a hands-on side to integrating team members which I believe the PM should hold himself accountable for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have him be instructed by the enior QA engineer.

Make him read all the documentation you got.

Have the devs take some time to explain features to him. That way he should learn to understand their general intentions and practices. Start with the most esential/most frequently tested (types) of features.

Allow him to spend time with the devs: set up lunches, joint breaks, after work events, ... They should get to know and understand one another.

Include him in all dev-related communication (chat rooms, mailing/notification lists, accounts in all kinds of tools).

Make sure to give him independent QA assignments (i.e., the kind that he himself is solely responsible for) as early on as possible. He should become self-sutained ASAP.

Have him write test cases and update documentation of features he tests.

Just off the top of my head.